# How to add background image behind the graph in android GraphView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-graphview, s7graphview

I am developing an Android app which plot point graph (scatter plot) using android GraphView library. I need to put a background image behind my graph. I tried,

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/cyan", null, getPackageName());
myplot.setBackgroundResource(imageResource);
```

("cyan" is the name of the image (.jpg format) and it is in drawable folder). But nothing happens. Can anyone make some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cyan);
myplot.setBackground(image);
```